# How to lock android home button,recent app button and back button for kiosk mode in android 4.4?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to lock android default button by using System alert window.its works fine up to android version 4.3 but doesn't works on android 4.4.
Please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into similar problem before. Using system alert dialogs to avoid user going to home or out of the application was a good idea. I assume that you are trying to do the same.

What I did was, run a background thread that will open up the activity (bring the activity to the front) of your application (if the application is not in front).

Depending upon the need to enable or disable this functionality, you can pause the background thread and start when appropriate, which will save the battery :).

Hope this helps.